# Access page session variables from class

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.5

In my web application(vb.net 4.6), I use session variables in all my pages.

It's using

```
Page.Session As HttpSessionState
```

I recently created a new public class within this project to hold some helper functions. In that class, I need to check some session variables, but I can't use `Page.Session` because it's not associated with an `.aspx` page. It's just a `.vb` type file.

I tried using

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

but it's always `null`.

How can I access my session variables from this new class I created?

Comment: You can always pass the HttpSessionState as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your helper class as an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) for `HttpSessionState`:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module HttpExtensions

    <Extension()> 
    Public Sub Print(ByVal state As HttpSessionState)
        ' a code here
    End Sub

End Module
```

or simply provide a parameter to your helper class.

Comment: Is the Module like a function?  So I could call the module simply by using MyHelperClass.Print()?  What would "state" be?  I just need to be able to access session variables.  Thanks.

Comment: `state` is a `HttpContext.Current.Session`, `Module` is a namespace for `C#`. Did you read the linked MSDN article?

Comment: So, on your page you can use this method like: `HttpContext.Current.Session.Print()`, but you need to import the module with helper methods: `Imports YOUR_APP_NAME.HttpExtensions`